# LibGdx, I moved ShapeRenderer projection matrix, but shadered waves did not move

Tags: opengl, libgdx, shaders, glsl, projection

I am use Libgdx with ShapeRenderer to draw rect and shaders passed to ShapeRenderer, to draw a waves. In game I made pseudo-parallax effect by changing projection matrix in SpriteBatches. But in ShapeRenderer+shader translating matrix leads to moving rect, but drawed waves didnot move
Please help

[image]
[image]

```
package com.mygdx.game;

import com.badlogic.gdx.ApplicationAdapter;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.InputProcessor;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.GL20;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShaderProgram;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.glutils.ShapeRenderer.ShapeType;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Matrix4;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector2;

public class MyGdxGame extends ApplicationAdapter implements 
InputProcessor
{

    private float mX;
    private float mY;
    private ShaderProgram mGradientShader;

    private Matrix4 mProjection = new Matrix4();

    private ShapeRenderer mShapeRender;

    public MyGdxGame()
    {

    }

    private float iGlobalTime = 0.0f;
    private Vector2 mScreenResolution;
    @Override
    public void create ()
    {
        final float screenWidth = Gdx.graphics.getWidth();
        final float screenHeight = Gdx.graphics.getHeight();
        mScreenResolution = new Vector2( screenWidth, screenHeight );
        mX = screenWidth / 2.0f;
        mY = screenHeight / 2.0f;

        String vertexShader = Gdx.files.local( "vertex.glsl" ).readString();
        String fragmentShader = Gdx.files.local( "fragment.glsl" ).readString();
        ShaderProgram.pedantic = false;
        mGradientShader = new ShaderProgram( vertexShader, fragmentShader );
        String s = "";
        if( false == mGradientShader.isCompiled() )
        {
            s = mGradientShader.getLog();
            Gdx.app.log( "Asteroid", s );
        }

        mProjection.setToOrtho2D( 0, 0, Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight() );

        mShapeRender = new ShapeRenderer( 19, mGradientShader );

        Gdx.input.setInputProcessor( this );
    }

    @Override
    public void render ()
    {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor( 1, 0, 0, 1 );
        Gdx.gl.glClear( GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT );
        Gdx.gl.glBlendFunc( GL20.GL_SRC_ALPHA, GL20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA );
        Gdx.gl.glEnable( GL20.GL_BLEND );

        mProjection.translate( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

        final int width = 400;
        final int height = 400;

        mGradientShader.begin();
        mGradientShader.setUniformf( "u_parentAlpha", 1.0f );
        mGradientShader.setUniformf( "iGlobalTime", iGlobalTime );
        mGradientShader.setUniformf( "iResolution", mScreenResolution );
        mGradientShader.setUniformf( "u_size", width, height );
        mGradientShader.setUniformMatrix("u_projTrans", mProjection );
        mGradientShader.setUniformf("u_center", mX, mY );
        mGradientShader.end();

        mShapeRender.begin( ShapeType.Filled );
            mShapeRender.rect( mX - width / 2.0f, mY - height / 2.0f, width - 100, height );
        mShapeRender.end();


        iGlobalTime += Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime();
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keycode) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyTyped(char character) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {

        mX = screenX;
        mY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY;
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchUp(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDragged(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer) {
        mX = screenX;
        mY = Gdx.graphics.getHeight() - screenY;

        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean mouseMoved(int screenX, int screenY) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(int amount) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return false;
    }
}

//###########################Vertex shader
attribute vec4 a_position;
attribute vec4 a_color;
attribute vec2 a_texCoord0;
uniform mat4 u_projTrans;
varying vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

void main()
{
    v_color = a_color;
    v_color.a = v_color.a * (255.0/254.0);
    v_texCoords = a_texCoord0;
    gl_Position =  u_projTrans * a_position ;
}


//###########################Fragment shader
#ifdef GL_ES
#define LOWP lowp
    precision mediump float;
#else
    #define LOWP
#endif

varying LOWP vec4 v_color;
varying vec2 v_texCoords;

uniform sampler2D u_texture;

uniform float u_outterRadius;

uniform vec2 u_center;
uniform float u_parentAlpha;
uniform float iGlobalTime;
uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform vec2 u_size;

float speed = 0.03;
float invAr = iResolution.y / iResolution.x;


void main()
{
    //determine origin
    vec2 position = ( gl_FragCoord.xy - u_center )  / u_size.xy;

    //determine the vector length of the center position
    float len = length( abs( position ) );

    float softness = 0.01;

    float waves_count = 2.0;
    float wave_spliter = 0.05;

    vec2 center = u_center / iResolution;

    vec2 uv = gl_FragCoord.xy / iResolution.xy;

//  vec3 col = vec4( uv, 0.5 + 0.5 * sin( iGlobalTime ), 0.0 ).xyz;
//  vec3 col = vec4( uv, 0.5, 0.0 ).xyz;
    vec3 col = vec3( 0.5, 0.5, 0.5 );

    vec3 texcol;

    float x = ( center.x - uv.x );
    float y = ( center.y - uv.y ) * invAr;

    float r = ( - 1.0 ) * sqrt( x * x + y * y ); //uncoment this line to symmetric ripples
    //float r = ( - 1.0 ) * ( x * x + y * y);
    float z = 1.0 + 0.5 * sin( ( r - iGlobalTime * speed ) / 0.003 );

    texcol.x = z;
    texcol.y = z;
    texcol.z = z;

    gl_FragColor = vec4( col * texcol, z * ( 1.0 - 2.0 * len ) );
}
```

Comment: perhaps rather than setting the projection in your shader, try  mShapeRenderer.setProjectionMatrix(mProjection); before your draw calls. My guess is that there is some sort of culling going on

Comment: @spectacularbob, Unfortunately it does not help

Comment: I think issue may be closed. I found solution. solution is in issue description. Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Спасибо за помощь
Я нашел решение:

```
private Vector3 mMatrixGetTranslation = new Vector3();
```

в render ()

```
mProjection.getTranslation( mMatrixGetTranslation );
float tranX = ( Gdx.graphics.getWidth() + mMatrixGetTranslation.x * Gdx.graphics.getWidth() ) / 2.0f;
float tranY = ( Gdx.graphics.getHeight() + mMatrixGetTranslation.y * Gdx.graphics.getHeight() ) / 2.0f;
```

и наконец

```
mGradientShader.setUniformf("u_center", mX + tranX, mY + tranY );
```